# Header name must be a valid HTTP token, nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create API which will return self hosted URL.
This is my code

```
const app = require('./app');
const config = require('./config/config');
const logger = require('./config/logger');
let server;
server = app.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
  logger.info(`Listening to port ${config.port} on host ${config.host}`);
});

app.get('/:sid/:ui',  (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('OK')
})
app.get('/url',  (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('inside')
  res.append(config.host+":"+config.port+"/:sid/:ui")
})
```

I am looking for result to be as

```
http://127.0.0.1:3005/sid/ui
```

When I hit the 2 url `http://127.0.0.1:3005/url` I get the following error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN]: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["127.0.0.1:3005/:sid/:ui"]
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:578:3)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\wgupta\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.append (C:\Users\wgupta\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:755:15)
at C:\Backend\temp1\src\index.js:14:7
```

Comment: `res.append()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What is the point of `res.append(config.host+":"+config.port+"/:sid/:ui")` and what exactly are you expecting that to do in the http response?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am looking for response as http://127.0.0.1:3005/sid/ui

Comment: `res.append(header, value)` is used to set custom headers on the response object.  You are only specifying the header and no value and why is the `:` part  of `:sid` and `:ui`.  This is not doing anything like you expect it to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Syntax issue solved it using

```
res.send(config.host+":"+config.port+"/sid/ui")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `res.send()` instead of `res.append()`